# Scraping airbnb price using goutte in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, goutte

Halo guys. now im learning about scraping using goutte in laravel. im using this https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte version. now im trying to scraping from airbnb site expecially for the price. until now i just success to get the hotel name but i unable to get the price

for example i want get the hotel name and the price from here site https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/1064946

here is my controller

```
$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/1064946');

$result = $crawler->filter('#summary')->each(function ($node, $i){
          return [
                  'hotel_name' => $node->filter('._12ei9u44')->text(),
                  'price' => $node->filter('._doc79r')->text()
                 ];
          });
```

but i still can't figure it out how to get the price. do anyone can help me?
im so currious about this.

Or there are have another function to scraping the css that load from javascript? i hear that PHP PhantomJs can do it. isn't it?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not use airbnb api?

Comment: There's a bug in your code. Anyhow, just check the code against known input and compare that to the expected output to get an idea what is wrong. Simple Test Driven Development.

Comment: @SaadSuri oh i didn't about API

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt oh i know where that bug.